# Given $a\leq b \leq c \leq d $ .How to prove $ c - b \leq d-a$

Tags: inequality

Given $a\leq b \leq c \leq d $ .How to prove $ c - b \leq d-a$.
I am facing this inequality again and again in Riemann integration ,but i couldnot figure it out

Thanks

Comment: a<b; c<d so a + c < b+d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try proving $$d-a\geq c-a\geq c-b$$

Note, you only really need $a\leq b$ and $c\leq d$. You don't need $b\leq c$.

The direct proof:

$$-b\leq -a\\c\leq d$$

adding:

$$c-b\leq d-a$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that since $a\leq b \leq c \leq d$ you have in particular that $c\leq d$ and $a\leq b$. You then substract from both sides. From $d$ you are substracting a smaller number so it follows that $c-b \leq d-a$.

Comment: Oh Thanks .This was easy and i was doing hell lot of computations

Answer (score 1):

$$\cdots\stackrel{a}{\bullet}\longleftrightarrow\stackrel{b}{\bullet}\longleftrightarrow\stackrel{c}{\bullet}\longleftrightarrow\stackrel{d}{\bullet}\cdots$$

Not a formal way to prove (you have answers to that allready) but intended to activate your intuition.

The distance between $b$ and $c$ (i.e. $c-b$) is "smaller" that the distance between $a$ and $d$ (i.e. $d-a$), right?

Answer (score 1):

Notice $a \geq b $ implies $-b \geq -a $ and since $d \geq c $, then adding the inequalities, we obtain $d-b \geq c -a $

Answer (score 1):

To Prove(TP) : $c-b \leq d-a$,

or, TP : $c+a \leq d+b$

Now, $a \leq b \; and \; c\leq d $ add these two inequality, to get the result

$a+c \leq b+d$

Answer (score 1):

$ a \leq b \leq c \leq d \Rightarrow$ 
$a \leq b$ and $c \leq d \Rightarrow$ 
$a + c \leq b + d $
$\Rightarrow c - b \leq d - a$

completing the proof.